# Fetch domain from database and compare if equal

Tags: database, parsing, fetch

1. Fetch URL from database
2. fetch domain from fetched URL
3. if fetched domain is equal to this Domain
4. show result

Thank you

Comment: Please add more context / details of what you are trying do to.  A  code snippet of what you are trying would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$banners = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT site_url FROM `banners` );
foreach($banners as $banner){
If ($banner['site_url']=='google.com or www.google.com'){
echo "this";
} else{
this"}
```

Site_url is not domain. its url google.com/translate/etc/etc. I want to extract domain and compare with google.com then result.

Thanks